# Скрипт на создание файла и поиск текста в нем

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell

Подумал, и решил сделать **bash-скрипт**,создающий **конвейер(pipe)**, который в свою  очередь производит такие манипуляци: создает файл с произвольными буквами+пробел, чтобы получались "слова"(-набор букв, с двух сторон ограниченных пробелом), заполняет этот файл на определенный размер этими "словами"(допустим на 3мб), далее делается поиск "слов" с определенной буквой(допустим - s), и в конце, найденные "слова" записываются в новый файл.

Это все хочется сделать используя только **bash** и **shell**.

*P.S.* Создавать файлы умею, но как их заполнить произвольными "словами" не нашел. Как это сделать? (Дублирование вопроса)

*P.P.S* Создал просто файл, руками его заполнил, сдела поиск букв "s"(`grep "s" myfile.txt`),а запись найденых слов в новый файл не получается. Как это сделать? (Дублирование вопроса)

Comment: "Подумал, и решил" - что лежало в основе раздумий? "используя только  bash и shell" - это не одно и то же?

Comment: *как их заполнить произвольными "словами"* — например: `$ sudo apt-get -y install wamerican; shuf -n 100 /usr/share/dict/american-english | tr '\n' ' ' > файл`

Comment: несвязанные вопросы надо задавать по отдельности.

Comment: К P.P.S. Пример использования конвейера `$ cat  myfile.txt | grep "s" > myfile2.txt`. Или так: `$ grep "s" myfile.txt > myfile2.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить случайный набор букв можно, например, при помощи `/dev/random` (длина не более 50 в данном случае):

```
head -c 50 /dev/random | tr -cd 'a-zA-Z'
```

Заполнить файл file1 сотней случайных слов, разделяя их пробелами:

```
for i in `seq 1 100`; do
    echo -n "" `head -c 50 /dev/random | tr -cd 'a-zA-Z'` >> file1
done

echo -n " " >> file1
```

Выбрать из этого файла слова с буквой s и перенести их в файл file2:

```
grep -oE '\s\w*s\w*\s' file1 | tr '\n' ' ' > file2
```

Comment: `strings /dev/urandom | head -n100 | tr '\n' ' '`